# return an array from a function in java android

Tags: java, android, arrays, return

how to return an array from a class.i am trying to do but it is showing an error

```
public String gettobill(String bill) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String col[]= new String[] { KEY_EBID, KEY_EMONTH, KEY_EBREAD, KEY_EBAMOUNT };
    Cursor l=ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, col, KEY_EBID + "='" + bill + "'", null, null, null, null);

    String[] eresult;
    int peid=l.getColumnIndex(KEY_EBID);
    int pemonth=l.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMONTH);
    int peread=l.getColumnIndex(KEY_EBREAD);
    int pamount=l.getColumnIndex(KEY_EBAMOUNT);

    for (l.moveToFirst(); !l.isAfterLast(); l.moveToNext()){
        eresult[0]= l.getString(peid);
        eresult[1]=l.getString(pemonth);
        eresult[2]=l.getString(peread);
        eresult[4]=l.getString(pamount);
    }
    return eresult;

}
```

Comment: Look at your method signature. You tell the compiler that you want to return a String and you return an array of Strings.

Comment: You also never initialized your `eresult` array.

Comment: `public **String**` should be your first clue...

Comment: how to solve the problem..can anyone give me the code

Comment: @ronal007 You need to understand why it doesn't work. Otherwise you'll always ask questions here. Read a basic tutorial about methods.

Answer (score 0):

Like in the comments, go through a tutorial and check your error message, it usually tells you what is wrong

```
public String[] gettobill(String bill) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String col[]= new String[] { KEY_EBID, KEY_EMONTH, KEY_EBREAD, KEY_EBAMOUNT };
        Cursor l=ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, col, KEY_EBID + "='" + bill + "'", null, null, null, null);

    String[] eresult = new String[5];//initialize your array before you can populate it otherwise eresult will be null and throw an exception
    int peid=l.getColumnIndex(KEY_EBID);
    int pemonth=l.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMONTH);
    int peread=l.getColumnIndex(KEY_EBREAD);
    int pamount=l.getColumnIndex(KEY_EBAMOUNT);

    for (l.moveToFirst(); !l.isAfterLast(); l.moveToNext()){
        eresult[0]= l.getString(peid);
        eresult[1]=l.getString(pemonth);
        eresult[2]=l.getString(peread);
        eresult[3]=l.getString(pamount);
    }
    return eresult;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
public String gettobill(String bill)
```

to

```
public String[] gettobill(String bill)
```